# ASP.NET MVC EF code first deployment GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, deployment, code-first, godaddy-api

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC code first application I'm trying to deploy on GoDaddy. I have gotten it to deploy using web deploy publishing from visual studio 2017. The sections that are not connected to the database run well. The pages that need to access the DB do not run and I get a SQL Connection Error. It will deploy perfectly on Azure. Can anyone offer any guidance on Code First Deployment for GoDaddy?

Any help or guidance will  be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message that you see? Have you contacted their support team? Make sure you use correct connection string. You can also read this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/.

Comment: Their support team does not offer deployment support. I have done everything in your suggested link, with no success. The error is: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. Is seems like a connection string issue.

Comment: Then ask them about correct connection string that you need to use. I know that their support is not good, but at least they can inform the connection string that you need to use. If they are unable to help, just change your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else who has googled fruitlessly for the code first deployment answer; the step that is missing in all of the guides can be found on this link, specifically under the Connection String header. Copy and paste your connection string from plesk in there.
https://support.everleap.com/kb/a1606/visual-studio-publish-web-deploy.aspx?KBSearchID=730082